# Activity tracking app to record horse riding styles

Tags: android, ios, sport, fitness

Is there an activity tracking Android/iOS app that can recognize horseback riding, and specific styles / gaits: gallup, trot, walk - and to save time duration of each during a ride?

Either automatically (which would be a dream), or at least semi-manually, like showing different speeds / shake levels with different colours, basing on manually-defined thresholds.

Comment: What purpose will the data serve?

Comment: For example to track from one ride to another whether it was more gallop-intensive ride--or, oppositely, more of walk, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [strava](https://www.strava.com/) app. While originally designed to track and compare physical activities mainly for running and cycling (by humans) you might try it out for horse-riding too. It has some neat analysis features, like graphs that show speed over time, energy consumption etc.. I use it for tracking my workouts.

To determine and depict the actual riding style in the captured data would probably be an intensive manual task, but, depending of what you actually want to compare between rides, not even necessary.

They are probably interested in adding specific features for horse-riders too. Good luck.

Comment: Good idea, but in 2016 this app still can't decide if a person was walking or running, so its got no show of picking the difference between a canter or a trot or a fall down a hillside.   Your only option would be to use the speed graph and somehow know that 3-6 mph is a walk, and 6-9 is something else, and anyting over 10 is probably a gallop.   Some phones have cadence sensors in them which might pick up different information, and if you want to get really flash there are ANT+ heart rate monitors which go around the chest of a human.  I have no idea how well that might work on a horse!

Answer (score 2):

You may also use the [runtastic](https://www.runtastic.com/en/apps/runtastic) app. A relative uses it for their walking workouts. It's quite similar in features as the forementioned strava app, but has a **built-in category for horse-riding**. I have never used the feature or the app personally, but others seem to have fun with it, [according to this blog](http://thehorsejunkie.blogspot.ch/2013/09/riding-as-exercise-its-possible.html).